# Weird black box when printing from javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I'm using windows.print() to print some content. I sometimes get a random black box on the right hand side of the print out. This happens regardless of whether I print to PDF or paper. Initially I thought it was printing the scrollbar, but this black box sometimes appears on the 2nd page also.

[image: A small part of the print-out that shows the mysterious black box]

I do not get the option of seeing a print preview. However, when I inspect the HTML that I'm printing, this black box does not exist, so it's definitely not my app generating this knowingly.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: In this particular case, we'll need the thing you are printing to test it ourselves.

Comment: That's content i cannot release publicly I'm afraid. Let me see if I can give out the HTML that builds the content. I'll post back in a while.